# Recursive method to count binary 1's

Tags: java, recursion, binary

So I have to run X / 2 through function recursively to find next position,
return 0;//return the number of 1's in the binary representation of the number X.

X mod gives us the 1 or 0.

This is the driver file:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    answer = A1Work.binaryOnes(i);
    correct = Integer.bitCount(i);
    System.out.println(((answer==correct)?"Correct":"Wrong") + " for i = "+i+" and correct = "+correct+" and your answer = "+answer);
}

System.out.println("-----------");
System.out.println("genericItem");
System.out.println("-----------");
```

Here's where I'm working:

```
public static int binaryOnes(int X) {
    if (X % 2 == 0 && X / 2 ==0) 
    return 0;
}
```

So my idea is I need to module. then divide after that module again if it's 2 or above.

I don't really understand what to do recursively or where to go from here.

I had a

```
void binary(int x)
int binary = binaryOnes(0).
```

Just very lost and looking for some insight.

Comment: `return x == 0 ? 0 : (x & 1) + binaryOnes(x >>> 1);`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of recursion is to break down an operation into one little piece and then do the operation on the remainder, accumulating a result as appropriate.

Since this seems to be an assignment, I'm not going to write your code for you. Instead, I'll describe the logic for one way of approaching this. (This is not the only way to do it.)

Think of counting the number of 1 bits as two subproblems:

1. Check whether the last bit is 1
2. Count the number of bits after shifting everything down one bit (dropping off the last bit). This can be done by a recursive call.

Your answer is either the result of step 2 (if the last bit was 0) or one more than the result of step 2 (if the last bit was 1).

Comment: My issue was over thinking and feeling that I needed a counter. since I thought you would do the module, divide, then see if you could do a module with the leftover division integer.

Answer (score -1):

The recursive function should check for an exit condition - when the input `x` is 0, return 0; otherwise find the last bit using modulo by 2 or applying a bit mask `0x01` plus recursive call to this function dividing the x by 2 or shifting right by 1.

**Update**
Initial code has not been tested and to address the issues with negative numbers the following changes need to be applied:

- for modulo/division version: the number of `1`'s should be defined as a difference between 32 and the number of bits in a bitwise complemented input
- for the bit mask/shift version: unsigned right shift `>>>` should be used

```java
public static int binaryOnes(int x) {
    if (0 == x) return 0;
    
    if (x < 0) return 32 - binaryOnes(~x);

    return x % 2 + binaryOnes(x / 2);
}    

public static int binaryOnesShift(int x) {
    if (0 == x) return 0;
    return (x & 1) + binaryOnes(x >>> 1);
}

// using library function for Integer class
public static int binaryOnesLib(int x) {
    return Integer.bitCount(x);
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (int x : new int[] {1, 0, -1, 2, 15, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE}) {
    System.out.print(x);
    System.out.print("\tdiv  : " + binaryOnes(x));
    System.out.print("\tshift: " + binaryOnesShift(x));
    System.out.println("\tlib  : " + binaryOnesLib(x));
}
```

Output:

```
1   div  : 1    shift: 1    lib  : 1
0   div  : 0    shift: 0    lib  : 0
-1  div  : 32   shift: 32   lib  : 32
2   div  : 1    shift: 1    lib  : 1
15  div  : 4    shift: 4    lib  : 4
-2147483648 div  : 1    shift: 1    lib  : 1
2147483647  div  : 31   shift: 31   lib  : 31
```

[Online Demo on JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/gvD)

Comment: `binaryOnes(-1)` returns `-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this made all my overthinking seem pointless. I wouldn't have thought I can just add them together based off how the problem was worded.

Comment: How did 7 work here though? shouldn't it pull 4

Comment: Dividing by 2 doesn't work properly with negative numbers. Also, for shifting, you need to use `x >>> 1` instead of `x >> 1`. You want to fill with zeros, not the sign bit, when you shift. Otherwise this will fail for negative numbers.

Comment: Well the code output properly I just don't know how it worked as 7 %2 = 1 then + 7/2 is lets say 3. thats 4. It's pulling 3 which is correct.

Comment: I changed it to X.....  public static int binaryOnes(int X) {
     if (0 == X) return 0;
     return X % 2 + binaryOnes(X / 2);
 }

Comment: Still don't understand how the 7 pulls 3 though in the end.

Comment: @hyperspacewoo, `7 = 4 + 2 + 1 = 0b0111` - there are three bits set to 1.

Comment: @user16320675, sorry my bad pasting :)